# Rails controller causing app to hang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, controller

I am using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2.0. Recently, I have noticed that my app will hang for long periods of time after a certain controller has been invoked. This is an app that has been under development for several years and I have never seen this sort of hanging behavior before (nor am I unfortunately completely aware of what changes I've made since it was last not hanging).

What I mean by "hang" is: No pages will load (no controllers can be reached, and even the default homepage which is basically a static page won't load). None of my logs will update. Standard output is not being written to. The application also has many background worker processes (managed by Resque), which also appear to be hung. This behavior will persist for minutes at a time.

In order to narrow down the culprit, I removed everything from my app except for one controller. That controller looks like:

```
puts "Peforming"

respond_to do |format|

  format.xml {

    render :xml => "<Status>OK</Status>"

  }

end
```

It will accept any POST from a client, and will respond with "OK," after printing a message. The app is hosted on a server, and I am hitting it with an XML POST as fast as I can from my local machine. After less than a minute of hitting it, the app will hang entirely, as described above.

I have also looked at netstat but see nothing out of the ordinary. There are lots of connections in the TIME_WAIT state, but I understand that that is fine. I also looked at top, and the machine is 90% idle, even when hanging.

Finally, this is running on Amazon EC2 in case that is relevant.

Comment: Seeing `puts` in a controller is usually a sign something's wrong. For debugging try: `Rails.logger.debug('...')`